# javascript settimeout div not showing

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have googled & I tried several answers but my problem is still occurring.  I have a .net web page on IIS 7 and the code works fine in IE9 but not in Firefox.  I need it to work in both. Not sure what I am doing wrong, please help.

It is a simple page with one multiline textbox that when i click submit a hidden DIV should pop up and say, Please wait while this processes...Don't click on anything.(they may submit 1000 items so it takes time.)

what's weird is i notice if i uncomment the Alert buttons, the alerts pop up and I actually do see the DIV, but if I take away the alert buttons, I am not seeing it.

here is my javascript.

```
function do_totals1()
    {
        // alert("Here-1");
        document.getElementById('pleasewaitScreen').style.display = 'block';

        // alert("Here-2!");
        do_totals2();

         window.setTimeout(function () {
         "do_totals2()";
         }, 4000);
        //            
        // alert("Here-3!");
        // window.setTimeout("do_totals2()", 1);
     }

function do_totals2()
    {
         alert("Here-4!");
         wait(4000);
         document.getElementById('pleasewaitScreen').style.display = 'none';
    }



<div id="pleasewaitScreen" style="display:none;position:absolute;z-index:5;top:50%;left:5%;">
 <table bgcolor="#000000" border="1" style="border-color:blue; height:300;width:400" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td style="width:100%;height:100%" bgcolor="#CCCCCC" align="center" valign="middle">
        <br /><br />  
        <font face="Helvetica,Verdana,Arial" size="5" color="#000066"><b>Processing... Don't click on anything until ESN(s) populate the grid below.</b></font>
            <br /><br />
        </td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: "Not Working" doesn't mean anything to us. What do you expect to happen? What actually happens? Have you read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)?

Comment: what happens when they submit the form? Is the do_totals1 function being called? Provide more info. It's incomplete.

Comment: This is not the source of your problem, but `"do_totals2()";` should not be in quotes. More importantly, it is pretty clear you are not showing us something because there are no loops in your code. As it is now, your code displays the `div` then immediately hides it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you're asking for:

```
function do_totals1() {
    document.getElementById('pleasewaitScreen').style.display = 'block';
    // we don't want to call do_totals2 directly, because it is what hides the element.
    window.setTimeout(do_totals2, 4000);  // setTimeout accepts a function reference
}

function do_totals2() {
    // if wait is effectively a thread sleep function, you don't want to use it.
    // if javascript doesn't release control of the thread (there's only one for your browser tab), 
    //the UI will never be updated, and you won't see that the element was shown.
    document.getElementById('pleasewaitScreen').style.display = 'none';
}
```

If all you are doing is showing an element then hiding it 4 seconds later, you can do this instead:

```
function do_totalsN(){
    var ele = document.getElementById('pleasewaitScreen');
    ele.style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(function(){
        ele.style.display = 'none';
    }, 4000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to show the "Please wait while this processes..." and then clear it after 4 seeconds, this'll do

```
function do_totals1()
{
    document.getElementById('pleasewaitScreen').style.display = 'block';
    setTimeout(function() {
        document.getElementById('pleasewaitScreen').style.display = 'none';
    }, 4000);
}
```

Comment: This one looks similar to shmiddty's so it should work as well.

Answer (score -1):

Well, basically you don't call it that way you either do this:

```
window.setTimeout("do_totals2();",4000);
```

or

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    do_totals2();
},4000);
```

So basically, remove the quotes and you will be fine

Here is more info

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp

Comment: Not the downvoter, but contrary to what w3schools states, you should never put `setTimeout` expressions in quotes. Use anonymous functions instead: `window.setTimeout(function(){do_totals2();},4000);`

Comment: totally agree with you, the reason why I would not place code within quotes is because it is rather annoying to evaluate when you have to pass a parameter. So personally I would never do that, but it is part of JS and its on the documentation too.